# Microsoft AdCenter V7 to V8 API

Tags: web-services

I am quite new to MS AdCenter API, I am wondering how can I find counterpart of classes in V7 in V8. For example GetCampaignsInfoByAccountIdRequest exist in V7 but does not exist in V8. Is  there a way to figure that out?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

i can only give the advice to search in the [adcenter api documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee730327%28v=msads.70%29) (which i think is really bad organized/usable and it is hard to find the information you want)

Concerning the *GetCampaignsInfoByAccountIdRequest*, maybe this procedure can help you:

Select in the sidebar the point "Microsoft adCenter APIs" (then you can see the menu points for API 7 and API 8 under it). Now use the search panel and type in: *GetCampaignsInfoByAccountIdRequest*. You'll see some results but only for v7 and v6... so i guess it is not available in v8 anymore.

For other classes do it in a similar way.. hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

The team recently [published an API transition page from v7 to v8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851100.aspx) which should answer such questions.